# Sourcing Vim with Janus

Tags: vim, janus

I am using Vim with [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) and I have [snipMate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) installed to handle various code snippets.

I changed one of these snippets and would like to see the change in my current vim window, without restarting Vim.

I tried sourcing:

```
~/.vimrc.local
~/.vim/vimrc
~/.vim/gvimrc
```

to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I wrote a slightly mean smart ass answer that contained this command lifted from SnipMate's doc:

```
:exec ReloadAllSnippets()<CR>
```

which works in the [original SnipMate](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim) but I thought "What if Janus used the new SnipMate instead?".

Indeed, it's using the [new SnipMate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) where this function has been removed.

I've read somewhere that the new SnipMate is loading snippets lazily so it's possible that reloading your current buffer (`:e<CR>`) is enough.